# Why is my Powershell code not to produce all the Azure users and their last sign in datetime?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

This is my code at the moment;

```
# Connect to Azure AD (if not connected)
Connect-AzAccount

# Construct the URI for user sign-ins
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns"

# Create an array to store the results
$results = @()

try {
    # Make the API call to retrieve all sign-ins
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers @{
        Authorization = "Bearer $((Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://graph.microsoft.com).Token)"
    }
    Write-Host $response 

    # Process the response and extract last sign-in date for each user
    foreach ($user in $allUsers) {
        $userSignIn = $user.UserPrincipalName

        # Filter the response to get sign-ins for the current user
        $userSignIns = $response.value | Where-Object { $_.userPrincipalName -eq $userSignIn }

        if ($userSignIns.Count -gt 0) {
            # Sort sign-ins by activity date and extract the latest one
            $lastSignInDate = $_.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime
        } else {
            $lastSignInDate = 'No sign-ins found'
        }

        # Construct the result object
        $result = [PSCustomObject]@{
            'User'           = $userSignIn
            'LastSignInDate' = $lastSignInDate
        }
        $results += $result
    }
} catch {
    Write-Host "Error retrieving sign-ins: $_"
}

# Export the results to a CSV file
$results | Export-Csv -Path 'OutputLocation\PowershellOutput.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

And at the moment this seems to produce `"No sign-ins found"` for the majority of users and just blank for the other users. The `"No sign-ins found"` are correct as this is a sandbox Azure and they are dummy accounts but the 3 that are showing as blank are actual account and should have sign in datetimes.

Can anyone assist in telling me what is wrong with my code as it stands please?

So far I have tried removing the `if ($userSignIns.Count -gt 0)` statment to instead just show all the users and their last login times but that doesn't work.

What I am expecting is to see the last sign in date of each user which should be obtained from sorting all the sign in logs descending of each user and then simply taking the first record.

Comment: What is `$allUsers` in your example? It would be much better to query the `users` api and use `$expand=signInActivity`

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I tried changing the uri to say
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=signInActivity" and used user instead of allUsers but now it shows all records as "No sign-ins found" and I know that is not correct.

Comment: my bad, I meant `$select` not `$expand`. So if you do this: `(Invoke-MgGraphRequest GET 'beta/me?$select=signInActivity').signInActivity` do you get any output ?

Answer (score 0):

**To fetch all the Azure AD users and their last sign in datetime, make use of below PowerShell script:**

```
Connect-AzAccount

$AccessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://graph.microsoft.com).Token
$headers = @{
    "Content-Type"="application/json"
    "Authorization"="Bearer $AccessToken"
}
 
#API URL for retrieving users with signInActivity.
$ApiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?`$select=displayName,userPrincipalName,signInActivity,userType"
 
$Result = @()
While ($ApiUrl -ne $Null) {
    # Perform pagination if next page link (odata.nextlink) returned.
    $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $ApiUrl -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers
    if ($Response.value) {
        $Users = $Response.value
        ForEach ($User in $Users) {
            # Check if LastSignInDateTime is empty or null
            if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($User.signInActivity.lastSignInDateTime)) {
                $LastSignInDateTime = "No sign-ins found"
            } else {
                $LastSignInDateTime = [DateTime]$User.signInActivity.lastSignInDateTime
            }
            
            # Check if LastNonInteractiveSignInDateTime is empty or null
            if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($User.signInActivity.lastNonInteractiveSignInDateTime)) {
                $LastNonInteractiveSignInDateTime = $null
            } else {
                $LastNonInteractiveSignInDateTime = [DateTime]$User.signInActivity.lastNonInteractiveSignInDateTime
            }

            # Construct result object
            $Result += New-Object PSObject -property @{
                DisplayName = $User.displayName
                UserPrincipalName = $User.userPrincipalName
                LastSignInDateTime = $LastSignInDateTime
                LastNonInteractiveSignInDateTime = $LastNonInteractiveSignInDateTime
                
            }
        }
    }
    $ApiUrl = $Response.'@odata.nextlink' # Move to the next page
}

$Result | Export-CSV "C:\Users\rukmini\Downloads\LastLoginDateReport.CSV" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

[image]

***The Azure AD user last sign in datetime exported successfully:***

[image]